# E/FirebaseInstanceId(29913): Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS. Won't retry the operation

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

E/FirebaseInstanceId(29913): Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS. Won't retry the operation.

I'm getting this error in debug window during debugging a flutter application which uses firebase Cloud messaging

I'm getting this error in debug window during debugging a flutter application which uses firebase Cloud messaging